# Make TypeScript return type depend on whether optional property is present

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typeguards

I have a function that looks like this:

```
function foo(a) {
    if(a.optionalProperty === undefined) {
        return {
            one: 1,
            two: 2
        }
    } else {
        return {
            one: 1,
            two: 2,
            optionalResultProperty: "some stuff"
        }
    }
}
```

The parameter a is one of the following two types:

```
SomeType & {
    optionalProperty: string
}

// or

SomeType
```

I would like to specify the return type so that it matches the function definition, meaning when the `optionalProperty` is present, the return type should be a certain return type and if it is not present, it should be a different return type.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
function foo<x extends (SomeType & { optionalProperty: string }) | SomeType>(a: x): x extends (SomeType & { optionalProperty: string }) ? SomeReturnType : Omit<SomeReturnType, "optionalResultProperty"> {
    // ..
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be correct. It says that the code is not assignable to the type.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seem to want here is to [overload the function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads). This should do the job in a more readable way.

```ts
type SomeType = {p: string};
type RetOne = { one: number; two: number };
type RetTwo = RetOne & { optionalResultProperty: string };

function foo(a: SomeType): RetOne;
function foo(a: SomeType & { optionalProperty: string }): RetTwo;
function foo(a: SomeType | SomeType & { optionalProperty: string }) {
  if ('optionalProperty' in a) {
    return {
      one: 1,
      two: 2,
      optionalResultProperty: "some stuff",
    };
  } else {
    return {
      one: 1,
      two: 2,
    };
  }
}

// Return type: RetOne
const ret1 = foo({p: 'some'});

// Return type: RetTwo
const ret2 = foo({p: 'some', optionalProperty: '1'});
```

Link to TypeScript Playground: https://tsplay.dev/wOa66m